# how can i insert xml file into oracle tables?

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to insert xml file into oracle table .Iam getting ORA-01704: string literal too long this error message.
Note:Not xml data into table.Iam trying directly insert xml file into table

Please help on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: xml can be quite large, exceeding the 2000 char limit of varchar... Use CLOBs

Comment: please provide the example of insert code.

Comment: It's not really as simple as providing insert code, you will need to alter the column datatype to CLOB.